# Fade from one Color to another

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

How would one go about gradually fading a sprite from one color to another?

Answer (score 7):

Use `Color.Lerp` to interpolate between two colours. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.lerp.aspx). Pass this as the color to `SpriteBatch.Draw`.

The arguments to `Color.Lerp` are the two colours you want to fade between, and a fade amount between 0 and 1.